# How to remove the responsive code from the Twenty Twelve theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been looking all over for a answer on this but i cant find one. I know for twenty eleven it was as simple as removing some css. But i cant for the life of me figure out how to make the twenty twelve theme in wordpress 3.5 non responsive. Anyone know how ?

Comment: Can you please explain, why you want it out? I can't think of a reason.

Answer (score 0):

The responsiveness of the theme is localized in the media queries.

Open the `style.css` file, and look for

```
 /* =Media queries
 -------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Simply delete all the lines until

```
/* =Print
```

And it should remove the responsive functions of the theme

Comment: i did that there is more too it this time

Comment: What do you want exactly to remove ? If you don't want your site to adapt himself to the device, you should replace all `rem` or `%` by `px` in `style.css`. But that will be painfull :p

Answer (score 0):

Rather than backwards engineer twentytwelve, you could choose the styles that you like from it and apply them to 2011 as a child theme.

Answer (score 0):

simply remove all the code related to media queries.